# call application/javascript only inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript which redirects the user in case its a mobile user to a web application.

```
</script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="http://...js </script>
```

In some cases the web application has a hyperlink back to the website.

In this case the javascript would redirect the user back to the web app.

To prevent this, i thought about giving an additional parameter which should bypass the redirection.

For example: http://example.com?redir=false

In case this parameter does not exist, the script from above should work, if the parameter is set to false, it shall not.

I started to write the function but got some trouble since I did not find out how to call the script.

```
    <script>
        function WebAppredirect(){
            var param = (location.search.split('redir=')[1]||'').split('&')[0]
            if param == "false"{
                //do nothing
            } else{
                //call script
            }
        }
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does param get set to?

Comment: Use cookies instead!

Comment: param shall not be set by default

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a solution.

```
 function web() {
 var script = document.createElement('script'); 
 script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
 script.async = true;
 script.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'url.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}
    function WebAppredirect(){
        var param = (location.search.split('redir=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
        if (param == "false"){
            //web();
        }else{
            web();
        }
    }
```

WebAppredirect()

Answer (score 0):

Call the script by adding it after your code. That file that you call that redirects the user put it where the //comments are.

```
<script>
        function WebAppredirect(){
            var param = (location.search.split('redir=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
            if (param == "false"){
                //Do nothing
            } else{
                if (screen.width <= 800) {
                    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
                } //In this case im just checking the size..
            }
        }
WebAppredirect()
<script>
```

Of course you will have another problem with this. Since you're not using cookies or session after the user refresh it will send him to the mobile version.

SO you really should check and use cookies for this one.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Also I would do this in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. Ok so I answered your question. You code is wrong. you need to do if(param == "false"){. I assume you know a bit of javascript if dont, you should ask why your code is not working. Assuming thats your problem my solution works. Im pretty sure. Anyway try my edit question.

Comment: Ive tested the code so its working. The only thing you need to do is set the correct mobile verification in the ELSE.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood my question. How do I call this: </script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="http://...js </script> in the function? Thank you for the code, but thats what i posted in the question.. there is no difference

Comment: Ah ok. Yes in that case i missunderstood it sorry for that! =) Cool that you've find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var qs = document.location.href;
var redir = false;

qs = qs.split('?');
if (qs[1]) {
    qs = qs[1]
        .split('&')
        .indexOf('redir=false');
    redir = (qs == -1)
}
```

The long 5th line takes the query string, splits it using '&' and searches for the string 'redir=false'. It should be enough, but there are million ways to achieve the same result !

Comment: so this is searching for the string, but does not answer the question how I call the script